# Is it possible to generate a read-only key for a symmetrical encryption (AES)?

Tags: aes, asymmetric, blockchain

I am working with hardware that can only encrypt with AES. The problem with this is that the message must be publicly verifiable on the blockchain, without the encoding key being exposed. This is the textbook use-case for asymmetrical keys, yet the hardware does not support this. I cant come up with a method myself where a message is encrypted with AES and decrypted with an asymmetrical public key and then read. Is there a way to do this in as few steps as possible?

An option i thought of is that the message gets decrypted by a server and again gets asymmetrically encrypted before being made public and then it is read on the blockchain. Ideally, there would not be a server in this solution.

Comment: Wait, irrespective of the content, the fact that you are writing data to a blockchain means that some digital signing i.e. asymmetric cryptography is already happening. The transaction can be verified by the public key or device of who is writing it.

Comment: You cannot magically turn symmetric encryption into asymmetric encryption. Either you have a shared key (symmetric) or you have a pair of matching keys (asymmetric). Apart from that verification is about making sure that something has not been changed (integrity check) or that something was authored by some party (signature). I don't know which kind of verification you talk about but both don't necessarily need encryption and encryption does not necessarily provide either of this.

Comment: there are important missing details, like: from where and when must who be able to encrypt / decrypt / sign / verify, which piece(s) of data. this question is too unclear to answer with a specific protocol suggestion without the context. this question also seems to belong in crypto SE.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. AES is a symmetric cipher; everything it can do is done with the same key for all operations, and can neither be decrypted nor integrity-verified without knowing that same key again.

There is a way to use symmetric ciphers as a sort of very bad hashing function. Use the message as the key (or possibly as several keys), and encrypt a known fixed message (possibly multiple times, once with each key). You could publish the resulting ciphertext "hash" (on a blockchain or wherever), and a message recipient would be able to repeat the process to verify that the message was correct. However, this is functionally equivalent to just hashing the message and publishing the hash digest directly; you gain nothing from the addition of the symmetric encryption step, and the whole process only makes sense it you lack cryptographic hash functions and don't mind your messages being limited in length. In any case, it's not going to protect the message, per se; all it would do is let recipients verify whether you had generated such a message, in a way that doesn't easily allow somebody reading the published "hash" to re-derive the original message.

Your idea of encrypting the message from the device to some private server, and then the server (which is the only other device that knows the AES key) decrypts the message and performs asymmetric crypto upon it, is viable. However, it obviously only works if you control that server, and you said you don't want to require having a server at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AES as an asymmetric encryption algorithm, otherwise a public key encryption algorithm like RSA will not be born.
You can try the methods used by HTTPS protocol to achieve similar functions.

HTTPS protocol uses public key cryptography algorithm (such as RSA) to encrypt the key of symmetric encryption algorithm and send it to the communication server.
The server then uses its own private key to decrypt the key of the encrypted symmetric encryption algorithm.

In this way, the two sides have established a secure communication.
If your server is completely unable to use the public key encryption algorithm (is this possible?), you should try to pass the key of the symmetric encryption algorithm to each communication point in a safe way before transmission (although this is not realistic).

Comment: Your second paragraph is almost completely obsolete; all modern TLS cipher suites (and thus all modern HTTPS) uses ephemeral Diffie-Hellman based key exchanges (specifically ECDHE, elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman ephemeral), rather than RSA key exchanges. DH-based key exchanges still have public and private components, but there's no asymmetric encryption involved in modern HTTPS, Otherwise, though, this is broadly correct.

Comment: @CBHacking Yes, the use of RSA in the example I gave is outdated, but this is just an example to help the questioner better understand my context.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to generate a read-only key for a symmetrical AES encryption.

However, you should reassess the claim that "your hardware that can only encrypt with AES". There are very lightweight primitives and it is very likely that it is indeed possible to use asymmetric cryptography there on your hardware (of which we have no details).